# docker environment variables aren't replaced

Tags: docker, variables, environment

I created a Dockerfile, which is based on the freeradius server image.
Locally I have a folder called raddb containing configuration files.

This setup needs to be installed at multiple places with all configuration parameters the same, exceptionally 2 things, an IP address and a password secret.
I want to do this with environment variables so I executed following command to start up my docker container:

```
docker run -e SECRET=password123 -e IP=127.0.0.1  -p 1812-1813:1812-1813/udp radius -X
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM freeradius/freeradius-server:latest

COPY raddb/ /etc/raddb/

RUN sed -i "s|<SECRET>|$SECRET|g" /etc/raddb/clients.conf
RUN sed -i "s|<IP>|$IP|g" /etc/raddb/clients.conf
```

With the 2 sed commands I want to replace my parameter placeholder with the environment variable value.

However when I start up my docker container, these are empty.

I guess this comes because the sed commands are ran during the docker build and at that point the environment variables have no value, so that's probably why.

How do I fix this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed commands are executed while building the image before the envs are set in `docker run`.
You can execute a script when the container is started with `CMD` and change the files there.
Only the last `CMD` is used so you have to call the original command (`freeradius`) at the end of the script.